# Net Electrical Force

Tags: electrostatics

If a metal is insulated from earth and if a charged object is held near one end of it but not touched , will the net force acting on the metal be zero ?

Answer (score 1):

No, there will be a net force because the charged object will induce a charge redistribution in the metal. See [electrical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_induction).

Answer (score 1):

In most cases (probably always), no.

Suppose the charged object has a positive charge. Then it attracts the electrons in the metal close to itself, creating a positive charge on the region of the metal away from the charged object. The force of attraction on the electrons of the metal is more than the force of repulsion on the positive region of metal, because they are closer to the charged object. So, on the whole, the charged object attracts the metal object.